# Feynman Diagram for Bragg Equation

Tags: feynman-diagrams

Did Feynman ever derive the Bragg equation as a particle representation using Feynman diagrams? And where is it available? I spoke to Freeman Dyson and he couldn't recall.

Answer (score -2):

Did you look at http://birdtracks.eu/ ?
Its a massive compendium on feynman diagrams

Comment: Thank you, but a search of text doesn't show any Feynman diagram for the Bragg equation.